# ¿Cómo saber el tiempo que demora cada método de ordenamiento?

Tags: java

```
public class MetodosOrdenamiento {
    //ALGORITMOS DE INSERCIÓN:

    public void insercionDirecta(int datos[]) {

        int temp, ptr;

        for (int i = 1; i < datos.length; i++) {
            temp = datos[i];
            ptr = i - 1;
            while (temp < datos[ptr]) {
                datos[ptr + 1] = datos[ptr];
                ptr = ptr - 1;
                if (ptr == -1) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            datos[ptr + 1] = temp;
        }
    }

    public void insercionBinaria(int datos[]){
        int temp,ultimo, primero,centro;

        for (int i = 1; i < datos.length; i++) {
            temp = datos[i];
            primero = 0;
            ultimo = i-1;
            while (primero <= ultimo) {                
                centro = (primero+ultimo)/2;
                if (temp <= datos[centro]) {
                    ultimo = centro-1;
                }else{
                    primero = centro +1;
                }
            }
            for (int j = i-1; j >= primero ; j--) {
                datos[j+1] = datos[j];
            }
            datos[primero] = temp;
        }
    }

    public void mostrarDatos(int datos[]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("[" + datos[i] + "]");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio y a leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Las preguntas con solo código, sin una explicación de lo que quieres y lo que has intentado, tienen realmente pocas probabilidades de obtener respuestas. Un saludo.

Comment: Tienes que tomar la hora a la que empieza el método y la hora a la que acaba de ejecutarlo y restar, así tendrás lo que le cuesta. Ahora te toca mirar un poco por tu cuenta para empezar a desarrollarlo, es muy sencillo.

Answer (score 2):

Al iniciar tu proceso define

```
long tiempo_inicio = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

al terminar puedes obtener el tiempo transcurrido en milisegundos :

```
long tiempo_transcurrido_ms = System.currentTimeMillis() - tiempo_inicio;
```

si deseas obtener el tiempo transcurrido en segundos lo realizarías de esta forma:

```
long tiempo_transcurrido_segundos = (System.currentTimeMillis() - tiempo_inicio) / 1000;
```

---

Ejemplo:

```
public void insercionDirecta(int datos[]) {

    //*Determina tiempo de inicio.
    long tiempo_inicio = System.currentTimeMillis();

    int temp, ptr;

    for (int i = 1; i < datos.length; i++) {
        temp = datos[i];
        ptr = i - 1;
        while (temp < datos[ptr]) {
            datos[ptr + 1] = datos[ptr];
            ptr = ptr - 1;
            if (ptr == -1) {
                break;
            }
        }
        datos[ptr + 1] = temp;
    }

     //*Obtiene tiempo transcurrido.
     long tiempo_transcurrido_ms = System.currentTimeMillis() - tiempo_inicio;

     System.out.print("Tiempo transcurrido: " + tiempo_transcurrido_ms + " milisegundos.");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Como bien te dice Pablo en el comentario tienes que obtener el tiempo de cuando empieza y termina, después hacer la resta.

Quiero añadir el código que puedes utilizar para conseguir lo que necesitas.

```
long start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
long estimatedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start_time;
```

Necesitas usar la función `System.currentTimeMillis()` para obtener el tiempo y hacer la resta.